# How to create a wikimedia account with email address using mediawiki api

Tags: mediawiki-api

Using Mediawiki v.1.28, I'm able to create an account, but I need to store the email address for the user in the newly created account. The documentation (found [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Account_creation/en#Simple_example)) indicates it's possible to create an account with `username`, `password`, `email`, and `realname`, but only `username` and `password` are getting stored when I try it.

The API sandbox docs (found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=createaccount&createreturnurl=http://example.com/&createtoken=29590a3037d325be70b93fb8258ed29257448cfb%2B%5C&username=Bob&password=ExamplePassword&retype=ExamplePassword&email=bob%40example.com&realname=Robert%20Example)) seem to suggest a multi-step approach, but I haven't been able to figure that out.

Many thanks to anyone who can help by providing the steps (in http request examples) that will show how to create an account with stored email address.

Comment: There are three steps: 1) get an account creation token via `action=query&meta=tokens`, 2) query the API via `action=query&meta=authmanagerinfo` to see what kind of fields are needed for the login (for example, the site might use some non-password-based authentication method, in which case there will be no `password`/`retype`), create a form and show it to the user, 3) submit the form values via `action=createaccount`. (Steps 2 and 3 can repeat multiple times if the account creation process itself takes multiple steps. That's unlikely but possible.) ...

Comment: ...If you know exactly what fields are needed for account creation (e.g. because you are writing the code for a wiki that you control), step 2 can be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I figured out how to do it. I found that the different account creation methods/forms could be combined into one request (using POST) like this:

```
/api.php?
action=createaccount
&format=json
&createrequests=MediaWiki%5CAuth%5CPasswordAuthenticationRequest%7CMediaWiki%5CAuth%5CUserDataAuthenticationRequest%7CMediaWiki%5CAuth%5CCreationReasonAuthenticationRequest
&createreturnurl=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F
&createtoken=fd4022e23f592fe3563693606f078a20587bc7d5%2B%5C
&username=testuser
&password=test
&retype=test
&email=testuser@example.com
&realname=Test+User
&reason=Added+via+API
```

The `createrequests` field is a list of tokens (representing Mediawiki modules?) joined together with the pipe ('|') symbol, each one of which has corresponding fields that can be submitted in the request. For my example above, I've included the `MediaWiki\Auth\UserDataAuthenticationRequest` token in that list, which allows for submitting the `email` and `realname` fields; including the `MediaWiki\Auth\PasswordAuthenticationRequest` allows you to send the `username`, `password`, and `retype` (password retype) fields; and the `MediaWiki\Auth\CreationReasonAuthenticationRequest` allows you to submit a `reason` (for account creation) field.

Comment: You don't normally need to specify `createrequests`. It's for the edge case when you don't want to submit a certain `AuthenticationRequest` even though you are submitting all of its required fields.

Comment: It seems that in order to have the `email` field stored in the database, the appropriate value (`MediaWiki\Auth\UserDataAuthenticationRequest`) needs to be provided in `createrequests`. An account can be created without `createrequests`, but then only `username` and `password` will get stored.

Comment: `createrequests` should default to all the requests. If that's not the case, you should file a bug.